# printf is not printing even after enabling buffering

Tags: c, printf

so I was having a problem with a big code that uses strings and file names. I had many issues with it and I addedd some printf in bwtween to Keep check of how the Code works. I couldnt get anything in the output so i decided to take to old good "hello world" program to see if printf was the issue.

so here is the Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void){

printf("hello world\n");
}
```

I thought Maybe it is a Buffering issue, so I have tried some variations like :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void){
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
printf("hello world\n");
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void){

printf("hello world\n");
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
}
```

still Nothing is printed. any idea on how to find the issue? ps: I am writing on Notepad and i execute using gcc on terminal. gcc is installed just fine and I am working on Windows.

I checked the file's path and it is fine. The command I use is `gcc filename.c`

Comment: You could try flushing the output with fflush

Comment: If you run from the terminal, the first example should work just fine. Are you sure that you're building with the code you show us? Check the paths when you save in Notepad, and compare it to the path in your command-line window.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude to avoid path Problems I usually go to where the file is and in I type in the paths bar 'cmd' this launches the terminal directly and set it to the Right path

Comment: Just to be sure, if you use the `type` command to display the source file, is it the file you expect? And please [edit] your question to include the complete command you use to build the program (copy-pasted as text).

Comment: can you tell us what commands you ran in the terminal? just to be sure. Lest you end up only compiling and not executing

Comment: @Chase I added the extra info you requested.

Comment: Yep, as I expected. `gcc filename.c` just compiles the file. It doesn't execute. You have an executable named `a.out` in your directory. Execute that to actually run the program. Please note that `gcc` is a compiler. [Here's](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs107/cs107.1212/resources/gcc) a full tutorial

Comment: @Chase yes, it is true. But how do I get the execution to stay. Because upon Opening it, it quickly dissapears

Comment: open it from the terminal.

Comment: Run it from the command-line window: `a.exe`

Comment: Run the program from the same window you type `gcc filename.c` in. `gcc filename.c<ENTER>a<ENTER>`. Then go back to notepad, edit your code and restart the compile/run/edit cycle :)